# Modern perl - ready to run applications - learning by examples - from what?

Tags: perl, moose, plack

I'm learning Modern perl - Moose, Plack etc. In much advices you can read "learn by examples" - so started searching for some ready-to-run applications written with Modern perl.

Browsed much pages like:

- https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/applications
- https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/websites_using_perl

and much more (perl.org and etc.) - and unfortunately - I'm not found any "ready to run" application written with Modern perl.

I'm not found any Moose/Plack - CMS, neither ShoppingCart, nor Blog or any web application. It is hardly to believe than they are not exists, so probably I'm searching in the wrong places.

Please can you point me into some "Ready to run" web applications written in Modern Perl (not only frameworks)? I checked all apps from the above links, and no one is Moose/Plack based.

---

#### Already found "modern" applications

Catalyst based:

- [MojoMojo](http://mojomojo.org/) (wiki) - [added by Ian Sillitoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821642/ian-sillitoe)
- [ShinyCMS](http://shinycms.org/) (cms) - [added by Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340355/mike)
- [Deimos](http://deimos.dhoss.net) (cms) - [added by Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340355/mike)

Other Moose/Plack applications:

- none yet

Comment: This was on topic in the good ol' days of Stack Overflow, but not any more, for exactly the reason you gave in your bounty message: it's hard to keep these things up-to-date. There are exceptions, though: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242) is still around because the C++ community really [actively maintains it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296094). To that end, maybe consider making the question community wiki and writing a CW answer so everyone can make changes easily.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Great idea. I converting my answer to community wiki-answer, regardles of the status of the question itself...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Mason](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mason/) - framework only, but *pure* Moose/Plack based.

Edit:

Some links after searching for "Catalyst" in the github (maybe, some are abandoned):

- https://github.com/niner/CiderWebmail - Perl/Catalyst/AJAX based Webmail
- https://github.com/shlomif/catable - CATAlyst BLog Engine - written by perl cats
- https://github.com/yusukebe/Kutter - A Web Application displays the tweets about everyone eating. It's sample of Catalyst, DBIx::Class, and Moose
- https://github.com/gshank/ravlog - Perl Catalyst blog
- https://github.com/bobtfish/CatalystX-JobServer - Asynchronous job AMQP job server and message handler, with long hair
- https://github.com/fayland/foorum - Foorum (a forum/BBS system based on Catalyst)
- https://github.com/Craftworks/Engage - Application Framework that includes Catalyst, TheSchwartz and App::Cmd
- https://github.com/orlandov/blogjob - Catalyst blog webapp (powered by MongoDB!)

and much more.

*Unfortunately, havent any idea how to search github for **non catalyst**, but still Moose/Plack applications.*

Comment: Converted the to community-wiki answer. Everyone is welcomed to edit and extend it.

Answer (score 8):

[ShinyCMS](http://shinycms.org/) is an open-source content management system which uses Catalyst and Moose.  It's still in it's early stages, but is definitely worth a look.

[Deimos CMS](https://github.com/dhoss/Deimos) is, as far as I am aware, still in its alpha stages, but may be of interest.

[Silki](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Silki) is a Catalyst-based wiki hosting platform, which uses Moose, Catalyst and Fey::ORM.

Silki is written by Dave Rolsky, and I highly recommend that you have a look at his [blog](http://blog.urth.org/).  It contains a great deal of really useful information, including ["How I Use Catalyst"](http://blog.urth.org/2009/08/how-i-use-catalyst.html).  And although it is not a ready to run application, you might find looking at the source code for [Chloro](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Chloro%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro) helpful.

Finally, [WebNano](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=WebNano) is a PSGI based framework - I know you are looking for apps, but as this is PSGI based, I thought it might be useful.

Comment: YES! I missed both of them. Thank you! :)

Comment: @kobame I've added Silki and some more information that may be of use.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at some of [Duck Duck Go's Github repositories](https://github.com/duckduckgo). It's Modern Perl, [using Catalyst](https://github.com/duckduckgo/community-platform/blob/master/cpanfile), and with a lot of Moose inside. [community-platform](https://github.com/duckduckgo/community-platform) project is a good beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at web application frameworks under Modern Perl - have you looked at Catalyst?

- http://catalyst.perl.org

One example of freely available application code under Catalyst would be MojoMojo:

- http://mojomojo.org/
- http://search.cpan.org/dist/MojoMojo/

Their tutorial is also a good place to see working code:

- http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Manual/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial.pod

Alternatively you could look at Mojolicious - might be an easier place to start off.

- http://mojolicio.us

Lots of cookbook type code here (not sure about large applications though)

- http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides

HTH

Comment: As I exactly told, not looking for the frameworks, but for the "Ready to Run" applications. I know catalyst. Mojolicious is **not** Moose based. And finally - Yes - the MojoMojo wiki is an a good example. Thank you for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You had mentioned Moose.  Along with the [Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0010/lib/Moose/Cookbook.pod), I've found the [Manual](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0010/lib/Moose/Manual.pod) to also be helpful.  There's also [A Gentle Introduction to Moose](http://www.catalyzed.org/2009/06/a-gentle-introduction-to-moose.html) and [Getting Your Antlers](http://www.catalyzed.org/2009/04/getting-your-antlers-a-moose-article.html) (both from [catalyzed.org](http://www.catalyzed.org/)).

Other than that, I'd recommend tinkering with stuff and seeing how it works.  Once you do that, if you have more specific questions, please post them.

Comment: How could write more precise "Want to see ready-to-run applications written with Moose/Plack"? Don't looking for Moose-Plack-Catalyst-Anything TUTORIALS and manuals, but for the *ALREADY DONE* (OpenSource) applications, written with Moose/Plack. Thank you for links anyway. :)